# How can I Join both the tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables.

tblHobby

```
ID    Hobby            
------------
1    Singing        
2    dancing        
3    Playing
```

Employee

```
ID   Names      
-------------
1   1;2             
2   1;2;3           
3   2
```

I want the following results after joining both the above tables..

```
ID     Name        Hobby     Value  
-----------------------------------
1     AAA        1;2       Cpu,Vga         
2     BBB        1;2;3     Cpu,Vga,Ram     
3     CCC        2         Vga
```

Comment: SQL Server version?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make much sense. Where do the names come from, where do `cpu`, `Vga` etc come from? What happened to `Hobby`?

Comment: Not clear about your tables data and where it fetching from?

Comment: You need to fix your design, at stop storing delimited data and normalise your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2017+ you can use the build-in `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` functions. For example:

```
DECLARE @tblHobby TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[Hobby] VARCHAR(24)
);

INSERT INTO @tblHobby ([ID], [Hobby])
VALUES (1, 'CPU')
      ,(2, 'VGA')
      ,(3, 'RAM');

DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[Names] VARCHAR(24)
);

INSERT INTO @Employee ([ID], [Names])
VALUES (1, '1;2')
      ,(2, '1;2;3')
      ,(3, '2');

SELECT E.[ID]
      ,E.[Names]
      ,STRING_AGG([Hobby], ',')
FROM @Employee E
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(E.[names], ';') T
INNER JOIN @tblHobby H
    ON T.[value] = H.[ID]
GROUP BY E.[ID]
        ,E.[Names];
```

Note, `STRING_SLIT` is not preserving the order.